# CMake: how to keep special characters in add_custom_command?

Tags: cmake

I want to add a target which run a perl one-line script and generate a file. The perl command looks like this:

```
perl -MFoo -MBar -E 'perl code inside'
```

I printed the code generated by cmake script. It is ok, although has some extra spaces:

```
'$obj=ExtUtils::Typemaps->new;  $obj->merge(typemap => "ExtUtils::Typemap::STL::String"); $obj->merge(typemap => "ExtUtils::Typemap::ObjectMap"); $obj->write(file => "/home/yangxi/projects/cmake-perlxs/test/build/module_compiled_typemap");'
```

However when I generate the project and run make (verbosely), I noticed the specicial characters in the code has been converted:

```
'bj=ExtUtils::Typemaps->new \ \ bj->merge(typemap\ =>\ "ExtUtils::Typemap::STL::String") \ bj->merge(typemap\ =>\ "ExtUtils::Typemap::ObjectMap") \ bj->write(file\ =>\ "/home/yangxi/projects/cmake-perlxs/test/build/module_compiled_typemap") '
```

It seems that:

- all '$' and one trailing character are recognized as an cmake variable, which are replaced by empty content;
- all spaces are escaped by '\';
- all semicolons are recognized as cmake list separator, and replaced by space.

So how can I disable this feature?

## accessories

This is the full cmake function:

```
function(perlxs_add_typemap_modules typemap_file)
    set(typemap_file_global ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${typemap_file})
    message("global typemap file: ${typemap_file_global}")

    foreach(curr ${ARGN})
        list(APPEND typemap_module_args "-M${curr}")
        list(APPEND typemap_script "" "$obj->merge(typemap=>${curr}->new)")
    endforeach(curr)

    message("module args: ${typemap_module_args}")
    message("module script: ${typemap_script}")

    set(whole_script "'$obj=ExtUtils::Typemaps->new;${typemap_script};$obj->write(file=>${typemap_file_global})'")

    # add typemap compile command
    add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${typemap_file_global}
        COMMAND ${PERL_EXECUTABLE} -MExtUtils::Typemaps ${typemap_module_args} -E ${whole_script}
    )

    # add to typemap file list
    set(_XSUBPP_TYPEMAP_FILES ${_XSUBPP_TYPEMAP_FILES};${typemap_file_global} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction(perlxs_add_typemap_modules)
```

Using a verbose makefile, this is the output:

```
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::Typemaps -MExtUtils::Typemap::STL::String -MExtUtils::Typemap::ObjectMap -E 'bj=ExtUtils::Typemaps->new bj->merge(typemap=>ExtUtils::Typemap::STL::String->new) bj->merge(typemap=>ExtUtils::Typemap::ObjectMap->new) bj->write(file=>/home/yangxi/projects/cmake-perlxs/test/build/module_compiled_typemap)'
```

If I add "VERBATIM" at the end of add_custom_command, the output is like this:

```
/usr/bin/perl -MExtUtils::Typemaps -MExtUtils::Typemap::STL::String -MExtUtils::Typemap::ObjectMap -E "'\$obj=ExtUtils::Typemaps->new" "\$obj->merge(typemap=>ExtUtils::Typemap::STL::String->new)" "\$obj->merge(typemap=>ExtUtils::Typemap::ObjectMap->new)" "\$obj->write(file=>/home/yangxi/projects/cmake-perlxs/test/build/module_compiled_typemap)'"
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `VERBATIM` flag to your `add_custom_command` call?

Comment: @sakra "VERBATIM" did too much work. I will get an extra "\" before all "$".

Comment: Can you add the `add_custom_command` call to your question?

Comment: @sakra Last week I'm too busy to work on this project. Now I added the whole function, and the outputs with and without "VERBATIM".

Comment: @jiandingzhe you are adding in empty string in `list(APPEND typemap_script "" "$obj->merge(typemap=>${curr}->new)")`. Is this intentional?